# Permission denied when creating locust report inside docker container

Tags: python, docker, locust

I'm currently trying to run locust inside a docker container and it works fine for everything except creating html/csv report.

This is what I have done:

I have created my own dockfile that extends the locust one (and just copy my file):

```
FROM locustio/locust

COPY . /test/

WORKDIR /test
```

I then run the locust tests like this:

```
docker run --name test -p 8089:8089 LocustImage -f src/tests/create_tests.py --run-time 30s --users 1 --spawn-rate 1 --html loadReport.html
```

But when I run this I get:

```
2021-06-07T08:28:15.6966999Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-06-07T08:28:15.6967735Z   File "/usr/local/bin/locust", line 8, in <module>
2021-06-07T08:28:15.6968335Z     sys.exit(main())
2021-06-07T08:28:15.6969642Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/locust/main.py", line 429, in main
2021-06-07T08:28:15.6970610Z     with open(options.html_file, "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
2021-06-07T08:28:15.6971572Z PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'loadReport.html'
```

I have also tried to add a volume like this:

```
docker run --name test -p 8089:8089 --volume /home/vsts/work/r1/a/report:/test/report LocustImage -f src/tests/create_tests.py --run-time 30s --users 1 --spawn-rate 1 --html /test/report/loadReport.html
```

But still the same issue. Anyone with an idea of what I'm doing wrong? Haven't found any good example how to get the report with locust inside docker.

Comment: Pretty sure your issue is that you need to provide the full path for the `loadReport.html` file, not just the file name.

Answer (score 1):

Figure it out now (or at least got a solution).

But first, the problem why --volume didn't work seems to be because of azure devops. Somehow it don't work when I run it in the cloud but if I use --volume on my local computer it works fine.

But in the end I just ended up with this fix in my docker file:

```
FROM locustio/locust

COPY . /test/

USER root

RUN mkdir -p /test/report

WORKDIR /test
```

I read that most people suggest that you shouldn't use root but at least it work and think it's fine in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, I got the same error with my `docker-compose.yml` when I tried to export a html report.

```yaml
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/locust/main.py", line 437, in save_html_report
  with open(options.html_file, "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/mnt/locust/app.html'
```

But I did something simple, I `touch app.html` file and `chmod 666 app.html` in same directory my yml is located, at the end I was able to export and save the report.

So you could have created an empty file `touch /test/report/loadReport.html` and grand permissions to it with `chmod 666 /test/report/loadReport.html` and you good to go :)

My `locust` docker-compose configurations for distributed `Load Test`, it's always easier with `yml` files:

**master node on server 1**

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  master:
    image: locustio/locust
    ports:
     - "8089:8089"
     - "5557:5557"
    volumes:
      - ./:/mnt/locust
    command: -f /mnt/locust/locustfile.py --master --expect-workers 2 -H http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8089 -u 100 -r 200 -t 100s --headless --print-stats --host=https://my-server-2-load-test.com -L DEBUG --html /mnt/locust/app.html
```

**worker nodes on server 2 and 3**

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  worker:
    image: locustio/locust
    volumes:
      - ./:/mnt/locust
    command: -f /mnt/locust/locustfile.py --worker --master-host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```